# UEFI USB boot error : No such device: /.disk/Info

Tags: boot, uefi, usb-drive

As the title states I'm getting this error

`Error: no such device: /.disk/Info`

And then it enters GRUB rescue .

When I try to boot Ubuntu(12.04.3) via USB drive in UEFI mode.
Booting works just fine in legacy mode though.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you tell what's spitting out that error? What do you see *before* the error appears? The `/.disk/info` specifier sounds like a Linux/Unix device path, but a GRUB rescue prompt would normally appear *before* Linux launches, which is a bit puzzling unless the computer is rebooting into GRUB.

Comment: Thank you Rod Smith for your response. The error occurs when I try to do a uefi boot of the pen drive through the bios menu. So when I try u initiate the boot I get a blank screen for a few seconds then I get the error.

Comment: Are you using AMD64 (the 64 bit) version of Ubuntu in the Live USB? If not, that may be the problem.

Comment: Yes , I am using the 12.04.3-desktop-AMD64 version of Ubuntu. I created the live USB using universal USB installer version 1.9.4.4

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in GRUB, or possibly in your firmware. If you're using a "live USB" boot of Ubuntu, there's little reason to favor an EFI-mode boot over a BIOS-mode boot, so I'd just use the latter, which works. If you have some reason to favor an EFI-mode boot, I recommend you look into replacing GRUB on the USB drive with [another boot loader.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) I know of no step-by-step procedure to do this with an Ubuntu live USB image, though.

Comment: I'm trying to install it in UEFI mode as I also have Windows 8 installed in UEFI mode on the same hard disk. Can you please elaborate what you mean by bug in my firmware ?

Comment: Your firmware is the software that's built into the computer and that handles the initial stages of the boot process. In years past, this was known as the BIOS, but new firmware is of the EFI variety, so the term "BIOS" isn't really accurate (although many people, and even manufacturers, continue to use it in reference to EFIs). Unfortunately, many EFIs are extremely buggy. Upgrading them can sometimes help -- check your manufacturer's Web page.

Comment: Thank you for all your help but I guess there is nothing anybody can do .

Comment: I managed to install Ubuntu 13.10 in UEFI mode. I threw a couple of errors at me but eventually managed to boot from USB and install is UEFI mode. Thank you for all your help Rod Smith

Answer (score 1):

Grub EFI bootloader searches `/.disk/info` file to find the root filesystem of Ubuntu.
Just create the corresponding file will be fine.

Not sure what specification it follows though, maybe it's ubuntu-only approach.

Comment: But what if this is USB stick? For example I create it to load LM21.1-cinnamon.iso. These error messages appears right before menu.